# Publish Azure App function project with multiple functions

Tags: azure

I am trying to publish an Azure function project from Visual Studio to a brand new Function App in Azure.

Unfortunatly, the publish script only publish one of the two functions to Azure. I do not see any folders about the missing function. I am trying to figure out how to publish both functions in a single Azure function App.

Do I need to change the host.json file? Do I have to change any settings in the project?

I am using the publish to Azure functionnality in Visual Studio. I created a profile connected to my azure account.

Thanks alot,

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the floowing instruction was missing in my csproj file:

```
 <None Update="FunctionName/file">
  <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
</None>
```

Doing so creates the correct directory in the fonction App allowing the App to detect the missing functions and displaying them to the portal.